# unable to install CDT in Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-luna

I have just downloaded [Eclipse Luna](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/) in his package [Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/lunar). I want to add [Eclipse CDT](https://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) to program in C/C++ (I know I can download CDT package, but I prefer this way, don't offer that option as an answer please).

When I tried to install it using Marketplace I didn't found Luna version.

If I use Luna update site, that retrieves CDT 8.4.0.201406111759, I got this error:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.net4j.jms.api,3.1.100.v20140218-1709
```

If I use Kepler update site, retrieving CDT 8.3.0.201402142303I, I got this error:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt,8.3.0.201402142303
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.codan.checkers,3.2.0.201402142303
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.codan.checkers.ui,3.2.0.201402142303
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.codan.core,3.2.0.201402142303
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.codan.core.cxx,3.2.0.201402142303
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.codan.ui,3.2.0.201402142303
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.codan.ui.cxx,3.2.0.201402142303
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.core,5.6.0.201402142303
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.core.linux,5.2.0.201402142303
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.core.linux.x86_64,5.2.0.201402142303
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.debug.core,7.4.0.201402142303
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.debug.mi.core,7.3.0.201402142303
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.debug.mi.ui,6.1.1.201402142303
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.debug.ui,7.3.0.201402142303
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user,5.3.0.201402142303
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.dsf,2.4.0.201402142303
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb,4.3.0.201402142303
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.gdb.ui,2.4.0.201402142303
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.dsf.ui,2.4.0.201402142303
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.cdt,8.3.0.201402142303
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.gdb,7.0.0.201402142303
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.cdt.gdb,8.3.0.201402142303
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.gdb.ui,7.0.0.201402142303
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.cdt.gnu.build,8.3.0.201402142303
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.cdt.gnu.debug,8.3.0.201402142303
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.cdt.gnu.dsf,8.3.0.201402142303
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.launch,7.1.0.201402142303
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.make.core,7.3.0.201402142303
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.make.ui,7.2.0.201402142303
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core,8.3.0.201402142303
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.gnu.ui,8.2.1.201402142303
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.ui,8.2.1.201402142303
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.cdt.platform,8.3.0.201402142303
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.cdt.ui,5.7.0.201402142303
No repository found containing: binary,org.eclipse.cdt_root,8.3.0.201402142303
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.net4j.jms.api,3.1.100.v20140218-1709
```

I added Eclipse CDT 8.4 update site (http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/8.4), it retrieves version 8.4.0.201406111759, same version than Luna update site, and obviously error was the same:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.net4j.jms.api,3.1.100.v20140218-1709
```

**How can I install Eclipse CDT in my Eclipse Luna instance?**

PD: Eclipse forums are not accepting my credentials of Eclipse account, I could not post my question there.

Comment: Try using the Luna update site http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna. Look in the Programming Languages section.

Comment: @greg-449 that was my first option that produced an error, CDT 8.3.

Comment: It lists CDT 8.4 for me

Comment: @greg-449 your are right, but I got second error. I will edit my answer. thank you for the tip.

Comment: For the eclipse.org forums, try clearing all cookies for the domain and re-try.

Comment: @E-Riz thank you for the cookies tip, I added same question in Eclipse forums: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/786033/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem. I was using **Oracle Java 6** to execute Eclipse. After upgrading to **Oracle Java 8**, the installation process executed correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Go to `Help > Install new software...`

Add the following URL: `http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/8.4/` and install CDT from there. The current Luna repository for CDT in Marketplace does not function properly, so the manual way is the way to go.

Comment: that is exactly what I did in my last option: "I added Eclipse CDT 8.4 update site (http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/8.4), it retrieves version 8.4.0.201406111759, ame version than Luna update site, and obviously error was the same:" and it failed as I exposed.

Comment: You could try installing Eclipse Standard and install everything separately from the Marketplace

Comment: your last comment does not fit my question. I wanted continue using same Eclipse version and flavour. check my answer.