# Install new software in Eclipse Luna gives always the error No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.net4j.jms.api?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I am using STS (Spring Tool Suite) with Eclipse Luna 4.4 and I noticed that everytime I try to install something (for example Apache IvyDE, Web Tools Platform)via *Help -> "Install new Software"* I get the following error:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=DefaultProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.net4j.jms.api,3.1.100.v20140218-1709
```

How can I get rid of this error and install Eclipse's software and plugins?

EDIT: here is what it looks like:

[image]

Then I click "Next", while eclipse loads:

[image]

There's a "Cannot perform operation" message on the progress bar, and after that:

[image]

Then I accept the license and after clicking finish I get the error:

[image]

Answer (score 17):

In the same dialog you'll see an option *Contact all update sites during install to find required software*, un-check it, ignore the prompt and click on *Continue*.

The above suggested solution worked when I've faced the problem. For this issue people are referencing https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=290782, a colleague of mine picked a solution from this comment https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=290782#c2

While all this solution are general to repository not found, I've found a thread discussing an issue with the plugin you mentioned, did you check it out already [unable to install CDT in Eclipse Luna](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24449208/unable-to-install-cdt-in-eclipse-luna). The OP in this question solved the issue by upgrading from Java 1.6 to 1.8.

Comment: I have tried to uncheck the Contact all update option, but it didn't work, please check my edit

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean with "remove the update site re-add the eclipse Project Update site"?

Comment: hey hey, sorry for not answering earlier, I've updated an answer not speaking from the top of my mind rather referencing the source that help some people in my team to resolve the problem, hope you'll manage, best

Comment: @tonix you need to disable all repositories except the one you will use, and uncheck `Contact all update sites during install to find required software`

Comment: @KhaledAKhunaifer thanks, I was able to solve already though! Anyway thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

I had the same exact problem, until I asked me the question: *what provide the `org.eclipse.net4j.jms.api` package ?*

I've [found this file in some git repository](http://git.eclipse.org/c/cdo/cdo.git/plain/plugins/org.eclipse.net4j.jms.api/plugin.properties) that looks like a configuration file for Eclipse plugins. What was interesting in that in the name of the provider: Eclipse Modeling Project.

With that, and the help of DuckduckGo, I've that the update site for this artefact is: http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/updates/

1. You should try to see what it contains using the "Install new software", after entering the URL in the first input field. **It is very slow to fetch**
2. You should be able to install or update (that was what I was doing).

I guess someone at Eclipse.org had the idea to update the repository, and that the system is so bad there is no way to tell Eclipse to look from old URL to a new. I'd rather like to see a *Eclipse Central Plugin Repository* like there is a *Maven Central Repository*, but that's another story.

Comment: Thanks a lot - this is the only solution that worked for me when trying to add plugins to STS 3.6.3.

Answer (score 4):

I also had an issue like this, my error message was:

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session
>   context was:(profile=epp.package.jee,
>   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=,
>   action=). No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.net4j.jms.api,3.1.100.v20140218-1709

In my case an inactive repository was responsible for the error. By adding it to the *Available Software Sites* with **Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse** and **http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/12.1.3.5/luna/repository/** the error could be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

## Ensure trailing '`/`' for all *Available Software Sites*

For the `No repository found containing: osgi.bundle...` problem I tried several options and the only one that worked was #2 in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15897080/5108777).

1. Help -> Install new software...
2. Click "Available Software Sites"
3. Ensure all the URLs have a trailing '`/`' (slash)
4. Try installation/update again

My version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)